# Asp.net mvc 4 foreign key in models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have these tables:

```
public class udb:DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<klasa> Keuni { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student> Seuni { get; set; }
 }
  public class student
    {
       [Key]
        public int studentid { get; set; }
        public string emristudent { get; set; }
        public int nota { get; set; } 
        [ForeignKey("klasaid"), Column(Order = 0)]
        public int klasaid { get; set; }
}}
 public class klasa
    {  [Key]
        public int klasaid { get; set; }
        public string emriklases { get; set; }
        public string vendodhja { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<student> students { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is that I want the klasaid to be a foreign key in students so when the user adds a new student the klasaid should exist in klasa model.I use Asp.net mvc 4.Can sb help me?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC. MVC is a framework for web applications, *not* a data access library. Are you asking about Entity Framework perhaps? Which version?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos do you understand my problem?I dont care about the mvc,just make it happen...to have a foreign key klasaid in students

Comment: That's something that's covered in Entity Framework tutorials. It's a basic concept - you can't proceed if you don't know how to map relations. You *have* to care about using the correct technology - otherwise you won't be able to find tutorials, documentation or help

Comment: Thanks for unhelping!

Comment: *Un*helping? You tried to execute a command that *updates the database schema*, even though the database exists. If EF hadn't blocked that, you would have lost data.

Comment: True I lost data,I lost the klasaid in student table.now I have to find a way to popultate just the klasaid in students table

Comment: Start by reading an EF tutorial. Jivan already pointed you to a tutorial site. MSDN has more. MVC tutorials typically have one or more sections on data management, eg [Getting Started with Entity Framework 6 Code First using MVC 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application). Visual Studio Essentials (free) offers 3 months of free Pluralsight courses, including some of the best EF and MVC courses

Comment: I am already watching some pl tut.They help,but now i am in this situation!and my deadline for the project is tomorro1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
public class student
{
        [Key]
        public int studentid { get; set; }
        public string emristudent { get; set; }
        public int nota { get; set; } 
        public int klasaid {get;set;}

        [ForeignKey("klasaid")]
        public klasa Klasa{ get; set; }
}
```

You can use [various](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) database initialization strategies as follows:

```
public class udb:DbContext
{
        public udb()
        {
          Database.SetInitializer<udb>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<udb>());
        }

        public DbSet<klasa> Keuni { get; set; }
        public DbSet<student> Seuni { get; set; }
}
```

One suggestion- follow proper [naming conventions](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards). Please, have a look into this [link](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx) for more details.

Comment: when I do Update-Database it gives me the error:The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.students_dbo.klasas_klasaid". The conflict occurred in database "Uni.Models.udb", table "dbo.klasas", column 'klasaid'.

Comment: `Update-Database` means "update my database schema from my class model". You don't need to execute it if the database already exists. This should only be a concern if you intend to update the database schema from the code model

Comment: What is your DB Initialization strategy?

Comment: @Jivan Idk what initialization strategy is.Please forgive my ignorance

Comment: You can check that there is not existing data in the database that is conflicting with the FK constraint causing the creation to fail.

Comment: @Jivan the colum klasaid in students table is gone...what should i do to empty the tables and put the colum klasaid in students again.and then populate them

Comment: @Jivan how can I empty tables?

Comment: If the data within your database is not important, you can drop and recreate

Comment: Can i do it from package console?

Comment: Do you want to drop data from all the tables?

Comment: I droped the tables from the database explorer but I have a question,When creating the tables from the database explorer do they automaticlly create model?

Comment: So, here comes the DB initialization strategy. Please, go over the links I provided in answer.